# 404 when trying to serve static files with non-english characters

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I have Windows 2008 R2 Server with IIS 7.5.
I am trying to serve static files with non-English (Hebrew) names, but cannot get it working.

I have 4 files:

- a.jpg
- א.jpg
- b.txt
- ב.txt

When I try to go to `http://.../a.jpg` and `http://.../b.txt`, I am getting the right files.
But when I try to access `http://.../א.jpg` or `http://.../ב.txt` it won't work.
Even if I encode the file names before going to url i.e `http://../%D7%90.jpg` it won't work as well.

I am getting a regular 404 server error:

> > 404 - File or directory not found.
> >     The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I tried the following, but it didin't help:

1.adding globalization settings to `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
      <system.web>
        <globalization
          fileEncoding="utf-8" 
          requestEncoding="utf-8" 
          responseEncoding="utf-8"
        />
      </system.web>
</configuration>
```

2.adding **.jpg** and **.txt** to `MIME Types` settings in IIS.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.
It was all about `UrlScan IIS extension`...

All I had to do is:

1. Go to the UrlScan folder inside `windir%\system32\inetsrv` [32bit] and `%windir%\syswow64\inetsrv` [64bit]
2. Open UrlScan.ini and change `AllowHighBitCharacters` to 1